# WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Whenever I run web aps in eclipse, I always got this warning:

```
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
```

What is this? What should I do about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or you could simply be using a web server that doesn't support Servlet 3.1. For example, Tomcat 7 only supports Servlet 3.0 and below. Whereas Tomcat 8 supports servlet 3.1.

Comment: But how to trace, where is this 3.1 attribute located? I'm having the same trouble, but the main setting is "<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" ...".

Comment: It should be in your web.xml. Not sure why you would get the warning if it is set to 3.0. Can you include the entire web-app starting tag?

Comment: We already fixed it somehow, I don't quite remember. Probably the setting was 3.0 but we used some 3.1 API's.

Comment: The interesting part is, we used Tomcat 8, which should've handled 3.1 APIs anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that is interesting. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a warning because the XML is incorrect but the app
should be running with an effective version of 2.3 based on the DOCTYPE.
Removing the unneeded version attribute would make that warning go away.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide more context of what was said here, I had in my web.xml the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mycorp.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And was getting the warning above for Tomcat 7. To make it go away, you need to change:

1. `web-app version="3.1"` to `web-app version="3.0"`
2. `web-app_3_1.xsd` to `web-app_3_0.xsd`

Hope this will help future readers.